# Data binding Express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm developing shopping cart as part of my learning.

**Homepage**
[image]

---

What I'm doing now:

**views/index.hbs**

```
<header>
  <div>Shopping cart<span class="badge">{{session.cart.totalQty}}</span><div>
</header>
  . . .
<a href="/add-to-cart/{{product._id}}">Add to Cart</a>
```

**routes/index.js**

```
// Home page route
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  Product.find()
    .exec(function (err, products) {
      res.render('index', { products: products});
  });
});
```

**routes/cart.js**

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function (req, res, next) {

  // access database and modify cart (update cart items quantity)
        req.session.cart = cart;
        res.redirect('/');    // redirect to Homepage
});
```

The code above, when `Add to cart` button has been clicked, the `cart.totalQty` is updated and the page is reloaded.

---

**Question:**  Is it possible to implement the feature that after button has been clicked, `cart.totalQty` get updated and header's badge get automatically binded according to `cart.totalQty` and render without reloading the page?

**Note:** I'm using "express-handlebars" modules i.e it's not included as handlebar.js in html.
Please tell me if I can provide more information.

Comment: Have you tried `$.ajax` ? That should help

Comment: I'm stuck. I tried changing `<a>` to `<button>` and handle click event by ajax call to `'/add-to-cart/:id'` route. Then update everything. But I don't know what to do next after updating. If I redirect as above, the page will be reload. If I response json back, I don't know how to bind.